# Use an image path from database as link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have an image being pulled from the database in a table, that I would then like to make into a link so the viewer can be taken to the full article.  I have seen that in theory I could use the below,

```
<%= link_to image_tag('image/someimage.png') + "Some text", some_path %>
```

but in my case 'image/someimage.png' is

```
<%= image_tag coffeeshop.image_thumb_path %>
```

I've tried simply dropping the image tag section in, so it becomes `<%= link_to image_tag('image_tag coffeeshop.image_thumb_path') + "Some text", some_path %>` but this doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

The first argument in your `link_to` will be interpreted as the body of the tag, and then your `url`, but if you want to add more content inside the `link_to` you can open it and then close it, all inside will be interpreted this way:

```
<a href="#">
  ...
</a>
```

So you can try:

```
<%= link_to some_path do %>
  <%= image_tag coffeeshop.image_thumb_path %>
<% end %>
```